# doctor-patient appointments database structure

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a small system with doctor-patient appointments.So, if the user is a doctor, he can tell the system when he is available for appointments and if he is a patient he could see all doctors' availability and book an appointment. There are and other functionalities for each role but these are the ones that I'm stuck with.There will be the patient and doctor tables and the appointment table that it is the middle table for the doctor-patient many to many relationship, it will have a patient_id(foreign key), doctor_id(foreign key), start_time and end_time. But, I cant think of how to implement the doctors' schedule and time slots. Do you have a similar example or an advice of how to implement this database in a quite simplified form, as im not trying to make something specialized.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Doctor HAS MANY Appointment
2. Appointment HAS ONE Doctor (usually... :) )
3. Appointment HAS ONE Customer
4. Customer HAS MANY Appointment

The appointment would have time and maybe location and some other details.
As long as there is no Customer assigned to Appointment it would be thrown in results as AVAILABLE.

To make it more accurate but more complicated you can create TimeSlot entity and it would HAS MANY appointments and Appointment would have one TimeSlot. 
You would have to set then kind of CRON job to generate slots for upcoming e.g. Month but do that e.g. In the middle of the month to keep 4 weeks or more in advance.

You can easily design this scheme in MySQL work bench.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So the doctor will be available if the appointment of a specific time slot does not have a customer? But there may be many doctors in a time slot that they have an appointment with different patients or no patients at all. Shouldnt we split the information in more tables? cause this is quite large. but anyways could you give me a relational model or some mysql code to understand better what you saying? thank you.

Comment: Edited my answer. Should work fine now for you. Use MySQL work bench to design it visually. If my answer helps please update and accept.

Comment: thanks, i got what you want to say but i want each doctor has its own monthly schedule for example.